# Problema de desplazamiento de personaje en juego tipo snake con Pygame (Python)

Tags: python-3.x, pygame

Estoy programando un juego tipo snake con el modulo pygame de Python. Tengo un problema con el desplazamiento de mi personaje (solo es un sprite, no es una serpiente). El personaje se desplaza de manera continua. Sin embargo, cuando pulso una flecha de dirección, el personaje cambia de dirección solo cuando toca el borde de la ventana. Quisiera que mi personaje pudiera cambiar de dirección cuando el jugador se lo pidiese. Aqui tenéis mi código:

```
import pygame, sys
import time
from pygame.locals import *



"""Valores constantes"""
weight_win=640
height_win=480

image_menu="menu.jpg"
image_background="fond.jpg"
pygame.init()

window = pygame.display.set_mode((weight_win, height_win))

pygame.key.set_repeat(400, 30)


class Astronaute: #Classe de personaje

    def __init__(self, right, left, up, down):

        self.x=0
        self.y=450
        """Imagenes del personaje para cada despazamiento"""
        self.right=pygame.image.load(right).convert_alpha()
        self.left=pygame.image.load(left).convert_alpha()
        self.up=pygame.image.load(up).convert_alpha()
        self.down=pygame.image.load(down).convert_alpha()
        """Imagen predefinida"""
        self.direction=self.right

    def move(self, movement):

        if movement=='right':
             self.x+=3
             self.direction=self.right 
    """Si gira a la derecha, se ve al personaje mirando hacia la derecha"""
        if movement=='left':
              self.x-=3
              self.direction=self.left
        if movement=='up':
              self.y-=3
              self.direction=self.up
       if movement=='down':
              self.y+=3
              self.direction=self.down

while True :

    welcome=1
    game=1
    menu= pygame.image.load(image_menu).convert()
    window.blit(menu, (0,0))
    pygame.display.flip()

    while welcome:

        pygame.time.Clock().tick(30)

        for event in pygame.event.get():

           if event.type==QUIT or event.type==KEYDOWN and event.key==K_ESCAPE:
                  pygame.quit()
                  sys.exit()

           if event.type==KEYDOWN:
               if event.key==K_F1: #Si tecla F1 apretada, se inicia el juego
                   welcome=0
                   background = pygame.image.load(image_background).convert()
                   ast=Astronaute("ast_right.png", "ast_left.png", "ast_up.png", "ast_down.png")


    while game:

        pygame.time.Clock().tick(30)

        for event in pygame.event.get():

            if event.type==QUIT:
               pygame.quit()
               sys.exit()

            if event.type==KEYDOWN:
               if event.key==K_ESCAPE:
                   game=0
```

Mientras que el x del personaje es inferior a la anchura de la ventana, el personaje solo se desplaza hacia la derecha.Lo he probado con un if en vez del while, pero entonces el personaje deja de despalzarse cuando el jugador deja de apretar la flecha derecha.

```
               if event.key==K_RIGHT:
                    while ast.x<=610:
                        ast.move('right')
                        window.blit(background, (0,0))
                        window.blit(ast.direction, (ast.x,ast.y))
                        pygame.display.flip()
               elif event.key==K_LEFT:
                    while ast.x>=0:
                        ast.move('left')
                        window.blit(background, (0,0))
                        window.blit(ast.direction, (ast.x,ast.y))
                        pygame.display.flip()
               elif event.key==K_UP:
                    while ast.y>=0:
                        ast.move('up')
                        window.blit(background, (0,0))
                        window.blit(ast.direction, (ast.x,ast.y))
                        pygame.display.flip()
               elif event.key==K_DOWN:
                    while ast.y<=450:
                        ast.move('down')
                        window.blit(background, (0,0))
                        window.blit(ast.direction, (ast.x,ast.y))
                        pygame.display.flip()

        window.blit(background, (0,0))
        window.blit(ast.direction, (ast.x,ast.y))
        pygame.display.flip()
```

Alguien me puede ayudar, por favor?